# Reading and writing classes with pointers to binary files in c++

Tags: pointers, file-io

I've been trying to write some data to a binary file in c++ using fstream and most examples go like this:

```
#include <fstream>

class Person{
public:
    int age;
    char name[50]; 
}

int main(){
    Person joe;
    joe.age = 50;
    strncpy(joe.name, "Joe Jones");
    fstream file("filename.dat", ios_base::binary);
    file.write((char*)joe, sizeof(joe));
    file.close();
}
```

This works just as expected but the problem arises when I try to write a more complex structure, mainly one with pointers instead of the actual data.

```
class Person{
public:
    int age;
    int *friendsAges;
    Person(int friends){
        friendsAges = new int[friends];
    }
}
```

When I write the data like before

```
Person joe(10);
/* Initialize rest of joe */
file.write((char*)joe, sizeof(joe));
```

the resulting file has 8 bytes of data, 4 for the `age` and 4 for the address of the `friendsAges` array or so it seems.

How could I go about writing the actual data that is stored in the array? I have also had this problem when my classes have other classes as members such as a `Person` having a `Car` or something like that.

Comment: What you are trying to do is called "class serialization" and if you search for that you'll find plenty of examples that should answer your question. I would recommend that you use `std::string` instead of `char[50]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For starters, add a method to your class that will perform the file I/O then you can just call it like so:

```
Person joe();
Person sally();

fstream file("filename.dat", ios_base::out | ios_base::binary);
joe.serialize(file, true);//writes itself to the file being passed in
sally.serialize(file, true); //write another class to file after joe
file.close();
```

Then later you could read that same file to populate the class instance:

```
fstream file("filename.dat", ios_base::in | ios_base::binary);
joe.serialize(file, false); //reads from file and fills in info
sally.serialize(file, false); //reads from file too
file.close();
```

The method in the class would look something like this:

```
Person::serialize(fstream &fs, bool bWrite)
{
    int ages_length;
    if (bWrite) {
        fs.write(&age, sizeof(age));
        ages_length = ...; //you need to know how long the friendsAges array is
        fs.write(&ages_length, sizeof(ages_length)); //write the length to file
        fs.write(&friendsAges[0], sizeof(int)*ages_length); //write the variable-sized array to file
        fs.write(&name[0], sizeof(char)*50); //write a string of length 50 to file
    }
    else {
        fs.read(&age, sizeof(age));
        fs.read(&ages_length, sizeof(ages_length)); //read length of array from file
        //TODO: you will need to malloc some space for *friendsAges here
        fs.read(&friendsAges[0], sizeof(int)*ages_length); //read-in the variable length array
        fs.read(&name[0], sizeof(char)*50); //this only works if string length is always fixed at 50
    }
}
```